# Ingress for MicroK8s argocd addon not working

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, microk8s, argocd, ubuntu-22.04

I have a working Microk8s cluster. After enabling the argocd community addon, the recommended ingress for argocd sever doesn't seem to be working.

Here's a note I got after enabling the addon:

```bash
Infer repository community for addon argocd
Infer repository core for addon helm3
Addon core/helm3 is already enabled
Installing ArgoCD (Helm v4.6.3)
"argo" already exists with the same configuration, skipping
Release "argo-cd" does not exist. Installing it now.
NAME: argo-cd
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Oct 20 17:34:33 2022
NAMESPACE: argocd
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
In order to access the server UI you have the following options:

1. kubectl port-forward service/argo-cd-argocd-server -n argocd 8080:443

    and then open the browser on http://localhost:8080 and accept the certificate

2. enable ingress in the values file `server.ingress.enabled` and either
      - Add the annotation for ssl passthrough: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/docs/operator-manual/ingress.md#option-1-ssl-passthrough
      - Add the `--insecure` flag to `server.extraArgs` in the values file and terminate SSL at your ingress: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/docs/operator-manual/ingress.md#option-2-multiple-ingress-objects-and-hosts


After reaching the UI the first time you can login with username: admin and the random password generated during the installation. You can find the password by running:

kubectl -n argocd get secret argocd-initial-admin-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 -d

(You should delete the initial secret afterwards as suggested by the Getting Started Guide: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md#4-login-using-the-cli)
ArgoCD is installed
```

Additionally, here's the Ingress that I defined:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-ingress
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: lets-encrypt
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    # If you encounter a redirect loop or are getting a 307 response code
    # then you need to force the nginx ingress to connect to the backend using HTTPS.
    #
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: argocd.DOMAIN.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: argo-cd-argocd-server
            port:
              name: https
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - argocd.DOMAIN.com
    secretName: argocd-secret # do not change, this is provided by Argo CD
```

When I visit the host address, I get this:

[image]

From the notes I got after enabling this addon, how do I do this part `enable ingress in the values file server.ingress.enabled` or get my ingress to correctly work?

Comment: "When I visit the host address, I get this:" You get what? Your image URL is invalid (does it need to be an image, or can you just post the text equivalent?).

Comment: @larsks updated with the image

Comment: The ingress looks like it's working; if you you were to click the "advanced" button, you should be able to click through to the web UI. It looks like cert-manager isn't able to successfully obtain a certificate; looking at some cert manage diagnostics might help. What is the status on your Issuer or ClusterIssuer? If the issuer is healthy, then look at CertificateRequest and Order resources, etc, until you find what's not working.

Comment: @larsks No such option in the advanced. Updated again the image. It seems that `server.ingress.enabled` has to be done before their own set secret can terminate their baked-in certificate issuing.

Comment: "No such option in the advanced" You're getting that because HSTS is enabled; you can of course reset that for your site (or bypass the warning); there are instructions online.for either option.

Comment: @larsks even after getting past HSTS. I get an HTTP 400 not found error so the ingress still not working to get to the service.